# Wordpress: An incomprehensible "value" is assigned

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

Please tell me what to do. It is not clear where the value goes from. How to remove it or replace it with value = "" so that only placeholde="Имя" remains. I'm using contact form 7 in wordpress

This is the code in cf7.

```
<label>
[text* your-name placeholder "Имя"] </label>
<label>
[tel* your-tel placeholder "Телефон"] </label>
<label>
[email your-email placeholder "Email"] </label>
<label>
[textarea your-message placeholder "Сообщение"] </label>
</br>
<div class="non-policy">*Отправляя форму, вы даете свое согласие на <noindex><a class="policy" href="https://.ru/policy.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >обработку персональных данных</a></noindex></div
[submit " "Отправить"]
```

This is what the browser shows.

```
<p><label><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="Имя" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Имя" /></span> </label><br />
<label><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-tel">
<input type="tel" name="your-tel" value="Телефон" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Телефон" /></span> </label><br />
<label><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
<input type="email" name="your-email" value="Эл. адрес" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email" /></span> </label><br />
<label><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
<textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea></span> </label><br />
</br></p>
<div class="non-policy">*Отправляя форму, вы даете свое согласие на <noindex><a class="policy" href="https://.ru/policy.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >обработку персональных данных</a></noindex></div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
```

Comment: have you the last version of Contact Form 7 ?

Comment: Yes, contact form 5.1.5